# How to convert a URL with URL encoding embedded in it?

Tags: javascript

So I have been given the following url:

`http%253A%252F%252Fmywebsite.unix.ampk.com%253A7777%252Fcustomloginpage%252Ftest.jsp`

And it's my understanding that un URL encoding, %253A is equivalent to a colon and %252F is equivalent to a forward slash.

I have some experience with working with regular expressions and I did look up `decodeURIComponent()` but I don't think I am on the right track here.

I was just going to iterate through the characters on this URL and run a replace method on it with some regex, but with that information regarding what URL encoding means for %253A and so on, I do not know if there is another way.

Comment: Try calling `decodeURIComponent()` on it *twice*.

Comment: @ChrisG, wow, that's a tricky one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL seems to be encoded twice.
Try runing

```
decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent('http%253A%252F%252Fmywebsite.unix.ampk.com%253A7777%252Fcustomloginpage%252Ftest.jsp'))
```

===> "http://mywebsite.unix.ampk.com:7777/customloginpage/test.jsp"

Comment: How did you figure out that it was encoded twice?

Comment: There was still encoded characters after the first decode.